# Does $u_n \to u$ weakly imply $u_n (t)\to u(t)$ for all $t\in [0,+\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Set $$W=\Big\{ u:[0,+\infty )\to \mathbb{R} \; \text{is absolutely continuous and}\; u'\in L^2 [0,+\infty)\Big\},$$ where $q$ is a non-zero constant. Assume that $$X=\Big\{ u\in W:\int_0^{+\infty}(|u'(t)|^2+q^2 |u(t)|^2)dt<+\infty\Big\}$$ with the inner product $$\langle u,v\rangle:=\int_0^{+\infty}(u'(t)v'(t)+q^2u(t)v(t))dt$$ which induces the norm $$\|u\|:=\Big( \int_0^{+\infty}(|u'(t)|^2+q^2 |u(t)|^2)dt\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$.

**My question:** Let $\{ u_n \} \subset X$ such that $u_n \to u$ weakly for some $u\in X$. Can we conclude that $u_n (t)\to u(t)$ for all $t\in [0,+\infty)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$, $Y$ are Banach space, $T:X\to Y$ be a linear operator, which is a compact imbedding, i.e., bounded sets of $X$ are mapped to pre-compact ones of $Y$, then:

If $\{u_n\}\subset X$, with $u_n\to u$ weakly, then $Tu_n\to Tu$ strongly.

In the case of the OP, for every $[a,b]\subset [0,\infty)$, let
$$
X[a,b]=\Big\{f: \int_a^b(|f'|^2+q^2|f|^2)\,dx<\infty\Big\}, \quad \|f\|=\Big(\int_a^b(|f'|^2+q^2|f|^2)\,dx\Big)^{½}
$$
then the imbedding
$T: X[a,b]\to C[a,b]$, with $Tu=u$, is compact (due to Arzelà-Ascoli), and hence weak convergence implies in $X$ implies weak convergence in $X[a,b]$, and finally strong in $C[a,b]$, and hence $u_n\to u$ converges uniformly in every $[a,b]\subset [0,\infty)$, i.e., it converges locally uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Weak convergence in $W$ implies weak convergence in $C([0,L])$ for all $L$. Weak convergence in $C$ implies pointwise convergence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me where I can find the reason of your comments? Why weak convergence in $W$ impliy weak convergence in $C$? and why weak convergence in $C$ imply pointwise convergence?

Comment: "why weak convergence in $C$ imply pointwise convergence?"   Among the linear functionals on $C([0,L])$ are the point masses $\varepsilon_x$ with $x \in [0,L]$; that is, linear functionals $f \mapsto f(x)$.

Comment: @M.Ramana this is the continuity of the embedding $H^1(0,L) $ into $C([0,L]$, where $W=H^1(\mathbb R)$.